# Show that if $|z| = 3$ then $8 ≤ |3z^2 − 5z + 4i| ≤ 46$

Tags: complex-numbers

Show that if $|z| = 3$, then

> $$8 ≤ |3z^2 − 5z + 4i| ≤ 46$$

How do I go about proving this? Should I use the triangle inequality here?

Comment: Yes, the triangle inequality works.

Comment: Yes, you can work it out with triangle inequality.

Comment: $|z_1|-|z_2|-|z_3|\leq|z_1+z_2+z_3|\leq|z_1|+|z_2|+|z_3|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mark, @Saucy and @Nosrati in the comments, we can proe the statement using the Triangle Inequality .

---

## Proof -

### Claim -

$\vert z \vert = 3 \Rightarrow 8 \leq \vert 3.z^2 - 5.z + 4i \vert \leq 46$

### Solution -

We have, by the triangle inequality -

$\vert z_1 \vert - \vert z_2 \vert - \vert z_3 \vert \leq \vert z_1 + z_2 + z_3 \vert \leq \vert z_1 \vert + \vert z_2 \vert + \vert z_3 \vert$

$\Rightarrow \vert 3.z^2 \vert  - \vert (-5).z \vert - \vert 4i \vert \leq \vert 3.z^2 - 5.z + 4i \vert \leq \vert 3.z^2 \vert +  \vert (-5).z \vert + \vert 4i \vert$

Since $\vert z \vert = 3 $, we have -

$3.3^2 -5.3 -4 \leq \vert 3.z^2 - 5.z + 4i \vert \leq 3.3^2+5.3+4$

$\Rightarrow 27-15-4 \leq \vert 3.z^2 - 5.z + 4i \vert \leq 27+15+4$

$\Rightarrow 8\leq \vert 3.z^2 - 5.z + 4i \vert \leq 46$

**Q.E.D.**

[image]